# How to display a report row in a form view as readonly in oracle apex

Tags: reporting, oracle-apex

I have a apex report that has many rows with various data type.
Now the user wants to view each row in detail. For this they want it to be in a form view.

But the form view must be conditionally read only (so that the user can not change anything if he does not have privilege).

I have found that , the interactive report of oracle generates a similar view for "single row view" ( although it is not conditionally editable).

In Another word, I want to show the row of a report by pivoting column to row.

Please help me how to do it.

(Creating a new form view and then make each element read only is a option , but it has many problem and is not suitable for over 50 reports.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your only option is to create the form pages, especially when you want editing. IR's don't have that kind of functionality built-in, and if you were to try and give them it through the `apex_item` API, you'd still have to write custom processes.
It would have been fastest to create the report+form combo upon creation (select form for new page, then form with report).
Now you'd have to select the query for your IR, and use this as a basis for your form query.
To make your items conditionally read-only, you can use the read-only condition on the items. If you use a `plsql function returning boolean`, you can even test an authorization scheme through `apex_util.public_check_authorization` (doc: [APEX_UTIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_util.htm#CHDJHBFJ))
And other than this route being grievously annoying and time-consuming, i don't know of these 'many problems' with it.

---

Now, if your form has to be conditionally read-only as a whole and not just certain items, you can solve it in other ways aswell.
**For both you'll have to create the form pages**: there is no way around this, and is the fastest and easiest.

1. conditional javascript+conditional process on form pages:

   - dynamic action, fire on page load. Execute javascript:

     ```
     $('input').prop('readonly', true);
     ```

     This will set all input items as readonly.
   - By using CSS you can make this clear to your users, for example

     ```
     input[readonly]{ background-color: grey; }
     ```

   They'll still be able to navigate and see a cursor, but won't be
   able to directly edit.   Of course, javascript is not enough.
   Someone can still alter values through using a tool like firebug or
   ie developer tools.   To stop that, change the conditions and/or
   authorization checks on both your dynamic action (only fire when
   user has no rights) and your record processing process (only run
   when user has rights). When a user has no rights, and manages to
   alter values and submit them, nothing will be sent to the database.
2. conditional link + form page:

   - Set the default link column of your report to show the report detail    view.
   - Create another link column on your report, which will link to your    form page.
   - Set the display condition or authorization of the second link column    to only show when the user is authorized to do so.
   - To prevent non-authorized users from going to said page and    manipulate the url to alter values of a record, you'll have to set
     an    authorization scheme to the page though. Or the processes,
     whatever    floats your boat really. Or use session-state
     protection. (good time    to read up on security i guess!)